# have Powershell get-childitem return files only

Tags: powershell

I'd like to use get-childitem recursively, but only have it return files not directories.  The best solution I have just doesn't seem natural:

```
gci . *.* -rec | where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "FileInfo" }
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Try this:

```
gci . *.* -rec | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
```

Comment: if you're excluding containers then you can leave off the * . *, right?

Answer (score 161):

In Powershell 3.0, it is simpler,

```
gci -Directory #List only directories
gci -File #List only files
```

This is even shorter,

```
gci -ad # alias for -Directory
gci -af # alias for -File
```

Comment: gci -File -Name  to get only the names of the files

Answer (score 0):

This is not working when anyone named the folder xxx.PDF:

```
get-childitem -Recurse -include *.pdf
```

Best then you can do:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.pdf | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
```

Comment: Some explanations are welcome.

Comment: Are you running powershell on Unix or another case-sensitive platform? I wonder if *.pdf needs to be *.PDF to match those files.

Answer (score -5):

In powershell 2.0 the best and simplest solution i came up with is to include all files with an extension:

```
get-childitem -Recurse -include *.*
```

folders doesn't have an extension so they are excluded, beware of no extension named files.

Comment: This (about directories) is not true. Nothing can stop you to have directory with extension

Comment: Bold assertion of yours, "folders don't have an extension"

It's quite typical to have dots in folder names, for example when they represent versions.