# Documentation for alias definitions for PowerShell arguments used with Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, alias

In an answer [here on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/541334/56229), it is pointed out that `gci -af` is an alias for `gci -File`.  That information is correct, and both command lines produce the same result of file listings.

However, I have not been able to find out a source of documentation where the `-af` alias is defined.  For example, it is not defined in the primary [documentation page for Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7).

Is there another set of aliases for command line arguments when the command name itself is abbreviated, as in using `gci` for `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: If you go down on the documentation link, you will see that `-File`s alias' switch parameter is `-af`.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio You are right.  In the browser I was surching for '-af' which was failing.  Please post as answer so I can accept.  Thanks so much.  This has been bugging me for a while now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Down on the parameter lists of the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7), you can find that `-af` is inded documented as an alias of `-File`.

> -File
>
> To get a list of files, use the File parameter. You can use the Recurse parameter with File.
>
> Type:                                              SwitchParameter
>
> Aliases:                                           af
>
> Position:                                          Named
>
> Default value:                                  None
>
> Accept pipeline input:                      False
>
> Accept wildcard characters:            False

Answer (score 1):

> Is there another set of aliases for command line arguments when the command name itself is abbreviated, as in using gci for Get-ChildItem?

There are several alias for the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet.

> [image]

Source: [Notes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7#notes)

> However, I have not been able to find out a source of documentation where the -af alias is defined. For example, it is not defined in the primary documentation page for [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7).

The alias for [-File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7#parameters) parameter most certainly is defined in the primary documentation page for [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7)

> [image]

Source: [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7)

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT - If I had the ability to define a table I would provide text.  Since that is not possible, and bullet points made my answer look ugly, I went with a screenshot instead.  I could have made the first screenshot text, but I had already taken the screenshots, and I submitted it through my phone.

Answer (score 1):

All cmdlet and parameter aliases can be seen this way:

- ```powershell
  # Get named aliases:
    Get-Alias |
    Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available aliases'

  # Get cmdlet / function parameter aliases:
    (Get-Command Get-ChildItem).Parameters.Values |
    where aliases |
    select Name, Aliases |
    Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Alias results for a given cmdlet or function.'
  ```

Another way of the above, but a bit different than your stated change, with the same results:

- ```powershell
  Function Get-CommandAlias
  {
    [CmdletBinding()]

    [Alias('gca')]

    Param
    (
      [string]$CommandName
    )

    Get-Command $CommandName |
    Select-Object -expand ParameterSets |
    Foreach-Object { $PSItem.Parameters} |
    Where-Object { $PSItem.Aliases -ne $null } |
    Select-Object Name, Aliases -Unique |
    Sort-Object Name
  }

  gca -CommandName Get-Help

    # Results:
      Name                  Aliases
      ----                  -------
      Debug                 {db}
      ErrorAction           {ea}
      ErrorVariable         {ev}
      InformationAction     {infa}
      InformationVariable   {iv}
      OutBuffer             {ob}
      OutVariable           {ov}
      PipelineVariable      {pv}
      Verbose               {vb}
      WarningAction         {wa}
      WarningVariable       {wv}
  ```

Yet another, before digging at parm aliases:

- ```powershell
  # Get a list of all commandlets for the specified name:
    Get-Command -Name '*Help*'  -CommandType Cmdlet |
    Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available named cmdlet'

    Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet |
    Where-Object { $PSItem.parameters.keys -match 'credential'} |
    Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available cmdlets which has a specific parameter'

  # Get a list of all functions:
    Get-Command -CommandType Function |
    Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available functions'

  # Get a list of all functions for the specified name:
    Get-Command -Name '*Help*' -CommandType Function |
    Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available named functions'

  # Find all cmdlets / functions with a target parameter:
    Get-Command -CommandType Function |
    Where-Object { $PSItem.parameters.keys -match 'credential'} |
    Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available functions which has a specific parameter'

  # Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function:
    (Get-Command -Name Get-Help).Parameters
    (Get-Command -Name Get-Help).Parameters.Keys
    Get-help -Name Get-Help -Examples
    Get-help -Name Get-Help -Full
    Get-help -Name Get-Help -Online

  # Get parameter that accepts pipeline input:
    Get-Help Get-ADUser -Parameter '*' |
    Where-Object {$PSItem.pipelineInput -match 'true'} |
    Select-Object -Property '*'

  # Get property enums/options for a specifc cmdlet/function:
    # 1:
      (Get-Service | Select-Object -First 1).Status.GetType()
      [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::GetNames([System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus])

    # 2:
      (Get-Service)[0].Status.GetType().GetEnumValues()
      (Get-ChildItem -Path $PWD)[0].GetType().GetMethods()

  # List of all parameters that a given cmdlet supports along with a short description::
    Get-Help dir -para '*' |
    Format-Table Name, { $PSItem.Description[0].Text } -wrap

  # List all loaded session modules and the exposed cmdlets / functions in them:
    Get-Module -Name '*' |
    ForEach-Object { Get-Command -Module $PSItem } |
    Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available loaded modules and their cmdlets / functions'

  # Get a list of specific cmdlets/functions in a module:
    (Get-Module -Name 'PSReadline' -All).ExportedCommands |
    Out-GridView -PassThru -Title "Available loaded modules and their cmdlets / functions"
  ```

Comment: THANK YOU!.  Your examples are absolutely out of this world.
For your second example, prior to piping the results to Out-GridView, I changed the display order as: `select Aliases, Name` and added `| sort Aliases`, which allowes me to see the results indexed by alias.
Again, incredible answer, thank you once more.

Comment: No worries, glad it provided a little more to chew on for you. I teach PS courses/sessions/talks to my internal teams, customer sites, etc. So, I am always pressing must attendees to master use all the help PowerShell can spin up.  What I gave is a small snippet of a much larger file [Consolidated PowerShell Help Resources and Options.ps1 - currently almost 3208 lines of info that I regular modify as needed] I give to my attendees and I encourage them to tweak it as they see fit or of course use it as is. Check the samples just added for you.

Comment: I am going to post another question based on your second example, and would like you to please look at it.  I am not adding it here as a comment, so that you can get credit, and to comply with the rules of the site.

Comment: Thank you for the additional content.
Here's that question I just posted: https://superuser.com/questions/1556393/how-does-the-equals-mechanism-work-in-powershell-to-see-null-results

Comment: Hey, Sabuncu, no worries, and I just got on the site today to see this. I saw others have already responded to you on this and the JosefZ is the most prudent and the way I would have responded. As for getting the credit, well, I get them if I answer early enough in most cases, but these folks got to you first. ;-}, so, only fair to award to whoever gives you the most appropriate answer. But I did provide another approach, well, just becasue.  ;-}

Comment: Postanote, I think you should put together a video training course on PowerShell, if you haven't done so already.

Comment: I have done such things as custom course for my team and customers, but not anything public. I have folks ask me to spin up a Youtube channel and do that as well. I just never got around to it. I've been and MCT (Microsoft Certified Trainer) for a little over 2+ decades and have taught many of the MS PowerShell MOCs' as well as the PowerShell courses. [https://www.microsoftondemand.com/courses/microsoft-course-10961 and https://www.microsoftondemand.com/courses/microsoft-course-10962]. They are still good for folsk today as well.